# Canonical sheaf of total space of vector bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety and $E$ be a vector bundle on $X$. Let
$$Y = Spec(Sym(E^*)).$$
How can I compute the canonical bundle $\omega_Y$ on $Y$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, the relative tangent bundle of $Y$ over $X$ is
$$
T_{Y/X} \cong p^*E,
$$
where $p:Y \to X$ is the projection.
Therefore,
$$
\omega_{Y/X} \cong p^*\det E^*,
$$
and hence
$$
\omega_Y \cong p^*\omega_X \otimes \omega_{Y/X} \cong p^*(\omega_X \otimes \det E^*).
$$